# Python Django Template Block Rendered Twice

Tags: django, django-templates

js block in page.html is getting rendered twice

end of page.html

```
    <script src="{% static 'LibreBadge/js/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'LibreBadge/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.toast').toast('show');
        });
    </script>
    {% block js %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

block js is

```
<script>
    function printRendering(){
        $('#badgeTemplateTempWrapper').append( $('#badgeTemplateWrapper>*') );
        $(' *').not('.printme *,.printme,body,nav *,head *,style,script,html,visibility:hidden').addClass('hiddenByPrint');
        $('.hiddenByPrint').hide();
        }; 
    function afterPrintRendering(){
        $('.hiddenByPrint').show();
        $('#badgeTemplateWrapper').append( $('#badgeTemplateTempWrapper>*') );
    };
    function replaceAttribute(id,attribute,value){
        $("#badgeTemplate").children()('#'+id).attr(attribute, value);
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tableSearch").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#resultsTable tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
    });
    });
    function rowClick(row) {
        document.badgeForm.EmployeeID.value = row;
        document.badgeForm.submit();
    }
    </script>
```

end of outputted html

```
    <script>
    function printRendering(){
        $('#badgeTemplateTempWrapper').append( $('#badgeTemplateWrapper>*') );
        $(' *').not('.printme *,.printme,body,nav *,head *,style,script,html,visibility:hidden').addClass('hiddenByPrint');
        $('.hiddenByPrint').hide();
        }; 
    function afterPrintRendering(){
        $('.hiddenByPrint').show();
        $('#badgeTemplateWrapper').append( $('#badgeTemplateTempWrapper>*') );
    };
    function replaceAttribute(id,attribute,value){
        $("#badgeTemplate").children()('#'+id).attr(attribute, value);
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tableSearch").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#resultsTable tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
    });
    });
    function rowClick(row) {
        document.badgeForm.EmployeeID.value = row;
        document.badgeForm.submit();
    }
    </script>


    <script src="/static/LibreBadge/js/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/LibreBadge/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.toast').toast('show');
        });
    </script>

    <script>
    function printRendering(){
        $('#badgeTemplateTempWrapper').append( $('#badgeTemplateWrapper>*') );
        $(' *').not('.printme *,.printme,body,nav *,head *,style,script,html,visibility:hidden').addClass('hiddenByPrint');
        $('.hiddenByPrint').hide();
        }; 
    function afterPrintRendering(){
        $('.hiddenByPrint').show();
        $('#badgeTemplateWrapper').append( $('#badgeTemplateTempWrapper>*') );
    };
    function replaceAttribute(id,attribute,value){
        $("#badgeTemplate").children()('#'+id).attr(attribute, value);
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tableSearch").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#resultsTable tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
    });
    });
    function rowClick(row) {
        document.badgeForm.EmployeeID.value = row;
        document.badgeForm.submit();
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

this question is being asked to solve a github issue on a project I maintain. The issue is linked below
https://github.com/LibreBadge/LibreBadge/issues/48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and am posting it in case someone else has a similar problem

my js block was outside of the for loop and if statement I used to select the badge templates. Look for template not found that's the snippet that was moved.

[image: diff view before and after]
before

```
{% block modal %}
{% endblock %}
{% else %}
Template not found
{% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
{% block js %}
    <script>
    function printRendering(){
        $('#badgeTemplateTempWrapper').append( $('#badgeTemplateWrapper>*') );
        $(' *').not('.printme *,.printme,body,nav *,head *,style,script,html,visibility:hidden').addClass('hiddenByPrint');
        $('.hiddenByPrint').hide();
        }; 
    function afterPrintRendering(){
        $('.hiddenByPrint').show();
        $('#badgeTemplateWrapper').append( $('#badgeTemplateTempWrapper>*') );
    };
    function replaceAttribute(id,attribute,value){
        $("#badgeTemplate").children()('#'+id).attr(attribute, value);
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tableSearch").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#resultsTable tr").not('thead tr').filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
    });
    });
    function rowClick(row) {
        document.badgeForm.{{ BadgeTemplateConfigFile.FormFields.0.id }}.value = row;
        document.badgeForm.submit();
    }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

After

```
{% block modal %}
{% block js %}
    <script>
    function printRendering(){
        $('#badgeTemplateTempWrapper').append( $('#badgeTemplateWrapper>*') );
        $(' *').not('.printme *,.printme,body,nav *,head *,style,script,html,visibility:hidden').addClass('hiddenByPrint');
        $('.hiddenByPrint').hide();
        }; 
    function afterPrintRendering(){
        $('.hiddenByPrint').show();
        $('#badgeTemplateWrapper').append( $('#badgeTemplateTempWrapper>*') );
    };
    function replaceAttribute(id,attribute,value){
        $("#badgeTemplate").children()('#'+id).attr(attribute, value);
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tableSearch").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#resultsTable tr").not('thead tr').filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
    });
    });
    function rowClick(row) {
        document.badgeForm.{{ BadgeTemplateConfigFile.FormFields.0.id }}.value = row;
        document.badgeForm.submit();
    }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
{% else %}
Template not found
{% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```